# simple hard coded ajax return value always undefined

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have an Ajax call and a PHP function. Firefox shows an HTTP 200 status. I can see the value "false" in the response, but it does not get passed to the `success` part of the Ajax handler; I always get undefined.

I have done a lot of Ajax before and many similar ones in my project and never had this issue. It is normal that the parameter is blank and should not affect anything.

I tried Async, print, return and even converting to JSON but not luck. No errors are showing up anywhere.

JavaScript:

```
function Init() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "php/file.php",
        type: "post",
        data: {
            action: "userInit",
            parameter: "",
            success: function(result) {
                alert(result);
            },
        },
    });
};
```

PHP:

```
function userInit() {
  echo('FALSE');
};
```

[firefox report #1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RWV3M.jpg)

[firefox report #2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3CJe8.jpg)

Comment: Does it reach to your php function? put `print_r('Testing string');die;` as a first line of `userInit` function. And check in browser network.

Comment: @HimanshuUpadhyay: We know it does from the second screenshot.

Comment: Looks like success is nested inside of data, that could be the issue

Comment: @FunkDoc: You're right. **Voting to close as typo/non-repro/not-useful-to-others-in-future.** Doer - If you format your code readably and consistently, this sort of error will be easy to spot. I've run the JS code in the question through http://jsbeautifier.org (no affiliation) for you. `success` shouldn't be *in* `data`, it should be next to it, at the same level as `url` and `type`.

Comment: Sure I understand, two days and did not see it. feel free to boo me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function Init() {
    $.ajax({
    url:"php/file.php",
    type: "post",
    data: {
        parameter: "123"
    },
    success: function (result) {    // Success is a callback function, it is part of your data object in the code which is wrong.
        alert(result);
    },
    });
};
```

Comment: That was it ! I really feels stupid. anyway feel free to boo me

Comment: Thank you so much @Doer. :-)